# Why is there a CALL instruction in this contract?

Tags: evm

This is a code snippet from a real contract. I wonder why the compiled code (can be obtained online from https://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity) has several CALL instructions, although the contract does not make any call?

```
contract ReleaseOracle {
  // Votes is an internal data structure to count votes on a specific proposal
  struct Votes {
    address[] pass; // List of signers voting to pass a proposal
    address[] fail; // List of signers voting to fail a proposal
  }

  // Version is the version details of a particular Geth release
  struct Version {
    uint32  major;  // Major version component of the release
    uint32  minor;  // Minor version component of the release
    uint32  patch;  // Patch version component of the release
    bytes20 commit; // Git SHA1 commit hash of the release

    uint64  time;  // Timestamp of the release approval
    Votes   votes; // Votes that passed this release
  }



  Version   verProp;  // Currently proposed release being voted on
  Version[] releases; // All the positively voted releases



  // proposedVersion retrieves the semantic version, commit hash and the current
  // votes for the next proposed release.
  function proposedVersion() constant returns (uint32 major, uint32 minor, uint32 patch, bytes20 commit, address[] pass, address[] fail) {
    return (verProp.major, verProp.minor, verProp.patch, verProp.commit, verProp.votes.pass, verProp.votes.fail);
  }
}
```